# How did Hertzsprung-Russell diagrams end up so confusing?

Tags: astronomy, notation, astrophysics

HR diagrams show in which of several sequences individual stars fall, each respecting the rough principle that hotter stars are of higher luminosity. (Sequences other than the main sequence [may bend or be close to level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#/media/File:HR-diag-no-text-2.svg), but let's put that aside.) Much about such diagrams takes some getting used to:

- We convey temperature on the $x$-axis and luminosity and the $y$-axis, and so might expect the main sequence to slope up. In practice it slopes down, because the $x$-axis is "running backwards": higher temperatures are on the left.
- Of course, the fact that the main sequence slopes down in this convention tells us the $y$-axis is "the right way up": the highest parts of the diagram have greater luminosity. But if you glance at the numbers on the $y$-axis, you might get the erroneous impression this isn't so, because the absolute magnitude $M_V$ falls toward the top. This is because it is a decreasing function of luminosity (a fact you'd never guess from the variable's name), specifically a negative logarithm of a nondimensionalised luminosity.
- Finally (this last concern is much lesser than the others), just in case the uninitiated's head isn't spinning enough, many values of $M_V$ are negative, which can confuse people trying to order the numbers too.

Needless to say, if we just put Kelvin on a logarithmic $x$-axis, increasing to the right, and wattage on a logarithmic $y$-axis (note that log-wattage will be positive even for very dim stars), increasing upwards, this would be a lot easier on everyone.

Now, part of the history behind this is that some decisions were made when we had a poorer understanding of what we were measuring. But this doesn't tell the whole story; as standards developed, one would expect rival diagram designs to be considered, and each option's pros and cons reviewed. How did astronomers settle on the status quo?

Comment: Your question is partially answered at physics stackexhange, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/338487/71627).